# From 6 random numbers calculate random three-digit number?

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I have 4 years PHP and C# experience, but Math is not my better side.
I thnik that i need in this project use some math algorithms.

When page load I need randomly create 7 numbers, 6 are numbers that I can use to calculate given three digit number:

- rand 1-9
- rand 1-9
- rand 1-9
- rand 1-9
- rand 10-100 //5 steps
- rand 10-100 //5 steps

and given number to calculate is 100-999,

I can use this operations: **+, -, /, *, (, )**

What is best algorithm for this? 
I probably need to try all possible combinations with this 6 numbers to calculate given number or closest number of calculations.

example:
let say that given three digit number is 
350, and I need to calculate this number from this numbers:
3,6,9,5 10, 100
so formula for this is:
(100*3)+(5*10) = 350

**if is not possible to calculate exact number, than calculate closest.**

You don't need to solve this problem completely, you can introduce me to solve this problem by paste some pseudo, or describing how to do that.

Comment: This is a highly unusual thing to want to do, could you give us some context as to why you would like to acchieve this? Also, are you allowed to use the numbers and operations multiple times?

Comment: It sounds like a programming puzzle, not a real-world problem.

Comment: @Glubus this is called as "my number" game. Users needs to find closer number than oponnent, when game finish i need to show how computer solve this problem.

Comment: codegolf.stackexchange.com may be a better place to look for this.

Comment: @user1814358 I see, sounds like a fun little game, before I post an answer could you react on the second part of my last comment?

Comment: @Glubus I can use same number once, same operators can be used multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no actual experience that might help you with this, though since you're asking for some insight, I'll share my thoughts on how to do this.

As I typed my answer, I realised that this is in fact a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which means you can solve it to optimality using any algorithm that solves the knapsack problem. I recommend using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in_advance_algorithm) to make your program run faster.

What you need to do is construct all numbers you can generate by combining two numbers with an operator, so that after this you have a list containing the numbers you started with, and the numbers you generated.

Then you solve the knapsack problem using the numbers as items with their value as their weight, and the number as the weight you can store at most.

The only thing that is slightly different is that you have an extra constraint that says that you may only use a number once. So you need to add into your implementation that if you add a combination of numbers, that you must remove the option of storing another combination that is constructed with the same number.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i am studying knapsack problem and i will try it soon.

Answer (score 2):

You could enumerate all the solutions by building "Abstract syntax trees", binary trees with the following informations :

- the leaves are the 6 numbers
- the nodes are the operations, for example a node '+' with the leaf '7' for left son and another node for right son that is 'x' with '140' for left son and '8' for right son would represent (7+(140*8)). Additionally, at each node you store the numbers that you already used (the leaves used in the tree), and the total.

Let's say you store all the constructed trees in the associative map TreeSets, but indexed by the number of leaves you use. For example, the tree (7+(140*8)) would not be stored directly in TreeSets but in TreeSets[3] (TreeSets[3] contains several trees, it is also a set).

You store the most close score in BestScore and one solution of the BestScore in BestSolution.

You start by constructing the 6 leaves (that makes you 6 different trees consisting of only one leaf). You save the closer number in Bestscore and the corresponding leaf in BestSolution.

Then at each step, you try to construct the trees with i leaves, i from 2 to 6, and store them in TreeSets[i].

You take j from 1 to i-1, you take each tree in TreeSets[j] and each tree in TreeSets[i-j], you check that those two trees don't use the same leaves (you don't have to check at the bottom of the tree since you have stored the leaves used in the node), if so you build the four nodes '+', 'x', '/', '-' with the tree from TreeSets[j] as left son and the tree from TreeSets[i-j] and store all four of them in TreeSets[i]. While building a node, you take the total from both tree and apply the operation, you store the total, and you check if it is closer than BestScore (if so you update BestScore and BestSolution with this new total and with the new node). If the total is exactly the value you were looking for, you can stop here.

If you didn't stopped the program by finding an exact solution, there is no such solution, and the closer one is in BestSolution at the end.

Note : You don't have to build a complete tree each time, just build the node with two pointers on other trees.

P.S. : You may avoid to enumerate all the solutions by using the dynamic programming approach, as Glubus said. In this case, it would consist, at each step (i) to remove some solutions that are considered sub-optimal. But with this problem I'm not sure that is possible (except maybe remove the nodes with a total of 0).